# How does the constant bound on Hormander's $L^2$ estimate for non-degenerate phase depend on the cut-off function?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, integral-operators, integral-kernel

A classical estimate, due to Hormander, assets that the integral operator

$$Tu = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} e^{i\varphi(x,y)/h} a(x,y) u(x) dx, \ \ a \in \mathcal{C}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{2d}), \ \ \varphi \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$$ can be extended to a bounded operator on $L^{2}$, if the mixed Hessian of $ \varphi $ is non-vanishing on the support of $a$. This has an sharp estimate 
$$ \| Tu \|_{L^2} \leq C h^{d/2} \| u \|_{L^2} , \ \ \text{as} \ \ h \rightarrow 0 $$
for some constant $C$. If the phase $\varphi$ behaves somewhat more badly, then it is difficult to obtain a similar bound as above.

In my case, I have a phase $\varphi$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which has vanishing Hessian on the diagonal, and I would like to know what kind of estimate I can get for the above operator. It seems to be a common practice in this case to split the domain of integration into two parts
$$ Tu = T \chi u + T ( 1 - \chi )u  $$
where $\chi$ contained the singular part of the phase. If I set $\chi$ to be a cut-off function supported on a ball of radius $r$, then using the cut-off $\chi(|x-y|)$ it is easy to bound to first operator with $ \|  T\chi\|_{\mathcal{L}(L^2)} \leq C r$. On the support of $(1-\chi)a$, I should be able to apply Hormander's estimate and conclude that $ \| T(1-\chi) \|_{\mathcal{L^2}} \leq C_{r}h $, the constant here depends on $r$.

In order to get a full intuition of whether this method would work, I wonder if anybody could tell me if there is a way to characterize the precise dependency of $C_r$ on $r$, or more generally, the amplitude $a$?

Many thanks in advance!